# Custom fetch api returning status 0 instead

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

So I implemented my own fetch api using Native javascript(xmlhttprequest) and will use it to fetch JSON data from github api. for some reason it gives out an error with status 0.

Here's the JSBin of custom fetch api where it's working: http://jsbin.com/jakahom/edit?html,js,console

When I change the url to fetch json data from github url, it seems to not work anymore. here's the jsbin for it: http://jsbin.com/girika/edit?html,js,output

Can anyone help spot what is the problem or missing in my fetch function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error due to the 'From' http header you are adding to the request.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.github.com/users/test. Request
>   header field From is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
>   preflight response.

```
var options = {
  method : "GET",
  headers: [{
    name: "From", 
    value: "admin@kennanseno.com"
  }]
};
```